# Li-Ion vs Li-Poly For Quads

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lipo, drone, quad-copter

Instead of using a $25 Li-Poly battery with a $10 charger, I was going to use one of these- https://hackaday.io/project/46436-3-cell-rc-battery-pack-made-with-18650-batteries What I was wondering Is how it would compare? It seems safer than a Li-Po, and cheaper, seeing how I have a bunch of those batteries sitting around, but performance wise, I'm clueless.

Comment: The Tesla model S uses them so I don't see why you shouldn't.

Comment: Because they're not the right kind of batteries.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong here:

1) A $10 charger is a bad idea, unless it's a trickle charger through the balance leads.

2) A $25 prismatic high-C lipo is a very different beast than 18650s, barring very specific ones (the LG HG2, Sony VTC5, etc) and very specific flight modes (minimum time-in-the-air of 30 minutes or longer).  Most 18650s are sub-1C discharge ratings.

3) You need to spot-weld the tabs to the batteries.  Do not solder them.

You also didn't say what kind of 18650s you already have.

Comment: sorry, i have these ultra fire ones... http://shopnis.ru/akkumulator-18650/ and I was going to rig them without welding, maybe make a really small holder for them, them I can pop them out and put them in my power bank and charge them from there

Comment: i mean, in a 3s2p configuration, it would be fine, right? check this out- https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?1880665-129min-15s-flighttime-with-quad

Comment: I can't stop you from doing it.  It's going to end in fire.  Those cells will live up to their name in this usage.